# How do I show the text longer than the textfield width in the material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently I am developing mobile enterprise web with ReactJs/Material UI and I have question How to show the user a character longer than the limited width `TextField`.

Of course, users can see all the characters by touching the text field and moving the cursor, but I need a more effective method.

Below are the ideas I have come up with.

1. Animation Effect? (When `TextField` is not touched, The effect of moving back and forth to make the entire text visible)
2. Display `multiline` text field when the user touches the text field. (dynamic `multiline` by whole length of text)

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd keep it simple:

- For long text (content, description...): I'll just set it to `multiline`
- For short text (email, password...) I'll set `fullWidth` on mobile.

There is no need to be overthinking. Look at the forms from the most popular websites you know, do you see anything other than `fullWidth` or `multiline`?

But if you set the `TextField` to `multiline` you can make it auto resize when there is not enough space to display the long text by setting `resize: both` in css. The default is `none` (disabled).

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textarea: {
    resize: "both"
  }
});
```

```js
<TextField
  label="MUI Text Area"
  multiline
  inputProps={{ className: classes.textarea }}
/>
```

Or simply:

```js
<TextField
  label="MUI Text Area"
  multiline
  inputProps={{ style: { resize: "both" } }}
/>
```

You can also use [`TextareaAutosize`](https://material-ui.com/components/textarea-autosize/) but it sucks and looks nothing like a MUI component out-of-the-box, so don't use it.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64592081/how-do-i-show-the-user-text-longer-than-the-textfield-width-in-the-material-ui]

Comment: Thank you. It is working for me. I thought so difficultly.

Comment: You can directly do `inputProps={{ style: {resize: 'both'} }}` to avoid `makeStyles`.

Comment: MUI should add this in their documentation in place of `TextareaAutosize`